# error registering serviceServer in golang gRPC using buf

Tags: go, grpc

I am trying to code a gRPC golang server, using buf.  I don't believe buf is the problem.   The project is at:  https://github.com/vinceyoumans/wc6

line 70 in server01/main.go

`crawlerpb.RegisterCrawlerServiceServer(grpcServer, &crawlServer{})`
is giving an error

Cannot use '&crawlServer{}' (type *crawlServer) as the type CrawlerServiceServer Type does not implement 'CrawlerServiceServer' need the method: MonitorCrawl(CrawlerService_MonitorCrawlServer) error have the method: MonitorCrawl(in *crawlerpb.MonitorCrawlRequest, stream crawlerpb.CrawlerService_MonitorCrawlServer) error

All of these methods I believe are implemented.

There are a lot of moving parts, so cannot add all of the code, but will document with specifics when I resolve problem.

any suggestions?

Comment: I think I resolved the question.   The solution was to remove the Stream from the rpc MonitorCrawl( stream MonitorCrawlRequest)...   this is a fix, as in it compiles and runs...  and listens. But I still have to see if it works with a client.

Comment: Try changing your crawlServer to CrawlServer

Comment: that is harder said than done because protoc/buf generate the code for gRPC...    But I resolved the problem.   thanks

Comment: [The interface](https://github.com/vinceyoumans/wc6/commit/e4bfe167df6e4ad1e58ee0e680bb1db133a83031#diff-474eb414f8e333df202b03657a35e5fdd8dc2273d54191d8d15b43f27b4ddf6fL93) specifies `MonitorCrawl(CrawlerService_MonitorCrawlServer) error` - you [implemented](https://github.com/vinceyoumans/wc6/commit/e4bfe167df6e4ad1e58ee0e680bb1db133a83031#diff-b3f66ad33325c073f0fae523300080af8ab77a8948a30f73cf9f745f5fcccbf3L153) `MonitorCrawl(in *crawlerpb.MonitorCrawlRequest, stream crawlerpb.CrawlerService_MonitorCrawlServer) error` (the interface has one parameter, your function two, hence the error).

Comment: Does anyone have any other gRPC examples?

Answer (score 1):

I think I resolved the question. The solution was to remove the Stream from the rpc MonitorCrawl( stream MonitorCrawlRequest)... this is a fix, as in it compiles and runs... and listens. But I still have to see if it works with a client

Comment: This is a fix if you don't require [bidirectional streaming](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/basics/#bidirectional-streaming-rpc) (which is what your original proto specified - `rpc MonitorCrawl(stream MonitorCrawlRequest) returns (stream MonitorCrawlResponse)`).

Comment: I agree....   my fix was to make this a server streaming gRPC app by removing the stream in the monitor request.